# Make batch copy requests to AWS S3 with Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I wrote a lambda function to copy files in an s3 bucket into another s3 bucket and I need to move a very large number of these files. To try and meet the volume requirements I was looking for a way to send these requests in large batches to S3 to cut down on overhead. However I cannot find any information on how to do this in Python. There's a Batch class in the boto3 documentation but I can't make sense of how it works or even what it actually does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no underlying Amazon S3 API call that can copy multiple files in one request.

The best option is to **issue requests in parallel** so that they will execute faster.

The [boto3 Transfer Manager](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3.html#copies) *might* be able to assist with this effort.

**Side-note:** There is no such thing as 'move' command for S3. Instead, you will need to *copy*, then *delete*. Just mentioning it for other readers.

Comment: I didn't realize I used "move" in my question. I meant copy.